# How to move SQL database from windows 7 to ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, windows-7

I want to move my database I created in windows 7 (with mysql workbench) to another pc running ubuntu (which has mysql-server installed). Is this possible?

Comment: It is possible, one option is to use [4.5.4 mysqldump — A Database Backup Program](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is. Use `mysqldump` command for export in windows and the `mysql < dump.sql` in ubuntu. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html for more information.